# How to declare a templated struct/class as a friend?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'd like to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    template <typename S>
    friend struct foo<S>;

private:
    // ...
};
```

but my compiler (VC8) chokes on it:

```
error C3857: 'foo<T>': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed
```

I'd like to have all possible instantiations of `template struct foo` friends of `foo<T>` for all `T`.

How do I make this work ?

EDIT: This

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    template <typename>
    friend struct foo;

private:
    // ...
};
```

seems to compile, but is it correct ? Friends and templates have very unnatural syntax.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
template<typename> friend class foo
```

this will however make all templates friends to each other.
But I think this is what you want?

Comment: can you please post reference section to standard where it's defined?

Comment: In C++03 in 14.5.3.3 and 14.5.3.4, In C++11 you need to read the Friends section in 14.5.4