# Accessing private member variables from a templated class assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates

I have a container class that is templatized. I am overloading the assignment operator such that derived types can also be assigned.

My problem is, when the type is not the same, I cannot access the private members of the container class. What is the best approach to gaining access? The member variables *cannot* be made accessible through public getters. Thanks!

Example Code:

```
// Note: var is private

template <class T>
Container<T>& Container<T>::operator=(const Container<T>& rhs) {
   if(*this != rhs) var = rhs.var; // works for same type
   return *this;
}

template <class T>
template <typename U>
Container<T>& Container<T>::operator=(const Container<U>& rhs) {
   if(*this != rhs) var = rhs.var; // does NOT work for different types
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: You need to make them friends, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292795/template-friend

Comment: Your equality check looks inefficient. Normally you would check `this != &rhs`. Better yet, use the copy-and-swap idiom to implement assignment.

Comment: It is just example code. In fact, the container class works like a smart pointer, thus the check is simpler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you want to access private members of template class instantiated with different types, you've to make other templates as friend of the template class as:

```
template <class T>
class Container
{
      template<class U> 
      friend class Container;

};
```

Note that if `T` and `U` are different types, then `Container<T>` and `Container<U>` are two completely different classes; one cannot access private members of other if you don't make friend one of other.

Also note that in the above code *all instantiations* of the class template are friend of *each other*. That is, if you instantiate it with `char`, `int`, `short`, then

- `Container<int>` will be friend of both `Container<char>` and `Container<short>`.
- `Container<char>` will be friend of both `Container<int>` and `Container<short>`.
- `Container<short>` will be friend of both `Container<int>` and `Container<char>`.

The interesting phrase here is : **"friend of each other"**. Usually this doesn't happen. For example, if you have a class like this:

```
class A
{
   friend class B;
};
```

Then here only `B` is friend of `A`. `A` is NOT friend of `B`. They're NOT *"friend of each other"*. `B` can access private members of `A`, but `A` cannot access private members of `B`. **That is the difference between this class and the template class above.**

Comment: Thank you. I figured `friend` was needed, but I never used the right syntax apparently.

Answer (score 1):

The first operator works because access is class-scope and not object-scope. That means you can access private members across instances of the same class.

To access a private member from a different class without using getters or setters you need to make your class friends with the other class.

Other ways involve hacks, accessing memory directly and are not portable.