# Refactoring using Abstract Base Classes and Templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, refactoring, class-design

I have a problem with some refactoring I am attempting. We have a lot of code duplication and I am trying to sort this out. I have the following class structure

**IMessageSink.h**:

```
class IMessageSink
{
public:
    virtual ~IMessageSink() { };
    virtual void process(const taurus::Msg& msg) = 0;
};
```

I have the following base class **ModelBase.h** which all models must inherit from, at this point please not the use of the `friend class EM`:

```
class ModelBase : public virtual IMessageSink
{
public:
   ModelBase(Tag a);

   void process(const taurus::Msg& msg);
   void reset();

private:
   friend class EM; // I will ask about this below.

   virtual void calculate(double lambda) = 0;
};
```

The implementation of `friend EM` is not correct and I ask about this below. I then have a class that implements/inherits from `ModelBase`, **ModelM0.h**:

```
class ModelM0 : public virtual ModelBase
{
public:
    ModelM0(Tag a);

   static ModelM0* ModelM0::make(Tag a)
   {
      ModelM0* m = new ModelM0(a);
      m->reset();
      return m;
   }

private:
    void calculate(double lambda);
};
```

with **ModelM0.cpp** implemented as:

```
ModelM0::ModelM0(Tag a) : ModelBase(a) { }

void ModelM0::calculate(double lambda)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

The problem is with the `EM` friend class and how to implement this in a generic fashion. Previously, this class only worked with types `ModelM0` which did not inherit from `ModelBase`. Now other models also inherit from `ModelBase` and `EM` needs to work with these as well - here lies the problem. I have the following definition in **EM.h** (which I have changed to a template so we can specify the type of `ModelBase` we are using `TModel`):

with **EM.h** as:

```
template <class TModel> 
class EM : public virtual IMessageSink
{
public:
    static EM* make(Tag a)
    {
        return new EM(a);
    }

    EM(Tag a);
    ~EM();

    void process(const taurus::Msg& msg);
    void run();
private:
    struct Bucket
    {
        TModel* _model;
        std::vector<TinyMatrix<1, 1> > _obs
    };

    EM::Bucket& getModel(int ag);
}
```

The problem implementation is `EM::Bucket& getModel(int ag);`, in `EM.cpp` we have

```
template<class TModel> 
EM<TModel>::EM(Tag a) { }

template<class TModel> 
EM<TModel>::~EM()
{
    run();
}

template<class TModel>
void EM<TModel>::process(const taurus::Msg& msg)
{
    int ag = getMessageCount(msg.type()); // External call.
    if (ag <= 3)
    {
        Bucket& b = getModel(ag);
        TModel* m = b._model;
        m->process(msg);
    }
}
```

The above seems to be okay, my problem is the implementation of `getModel`

```
template<class TModel> 
EM<TModel>::Bucket& EM<TModel>::getModel(int ag)
{
    // This is not right.
    TModel* m;
    m = TModel::make(getTag(ag)); // This is not right - I need a factory.

    // ... Do stuff.

    Bucket& b = // Get a bucket.
    b._model = m;

    return b;
}
```

My questions:

1. How can I change the above code so that in `EM<TModel>::getModel(int ag)` I can create the correct `TModel` using `make` in the above - do I need a factory and how would this be implemented?
2. In `ModelBase.h` the `EM` class is specified as a friend class. How can this me made generic to work with the `TModel` (`ModelBase`) type being used?

*It is important to note here that this is a refactoring question, not whether-or-not the code I have shown in the methods is proper or correct (this has been cut down in order to succinctly highlight my problems). The refactoring is the only thing I would like help with. Thanks very much for your time.*

Comment: Yes, because the code doesn't compile. Code review is for working examples only...

Comment: `do I need a factory and how would this be implemented?` factory pattern is usually considered when the created object consist of generic parts that can coupled together constructing the given object functionality...

Comment: Please add the compiler error(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to get your code compiling, I had to fix a few missing semicolons and missing types (`Tag`, `taurus::Msg`, `TinyMatrix`) and also fix the declaration and definition of `getModel(int ag)`

Generally, you need to indicate to the compiler, that `Bucket` is actually a type name and not some other sort of parameter.

For the declaration you have 2 options:

```
Bucket& getModel(int ag); // (1)
typename EM<TModel>::Bucket& getModel(int ag); // (2)
```

(1) is implicit usage of the Bucket type of your current template specialization. (2) is explicit type usage together with the `typename` keyword for the compiler, as mentioned above.

For the definition, you definitely need to `typename` keyword, since you are out of your class definition context.

```
template<class TModel>
typename EM<TModel>::Bucket& EM<TModel>::getModel(int ag)
{
    // This is not right.
    TModel* m;
    m = TModel::make(getTag(ag)); // This is not right - I need a factory.

    // ... Do stuff.

    Bucket& b = // Get a bucket.
        b._model = m;

    return b;
}
```

Just ignore the "This is not right." comments - I copied them over from your sample code. Its actually perfectly right.

For the `friend` declaration, you need to add a template version, since you want to befriend all possible template instantiations. I looked it up from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292795/template-friend) (Credits to Anycorn)

```
template <class> friend class EM;
```

Hope that solves all your issues. Note I used `template <class>` since you used it. Personally I prefer `template <typename>`.

Comment: I just re-read the question. Gonna look at the `friend` aspect, that I didn't consider yet. However, most of the time, needing `friend` is an indicator of underlying design problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and time here. I will implement your suggested change and come back with compiler errors...

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This has done the trick. The code compiles, and run perfectly as it did before this major change. You time is most appreciated. Thanks once again...