# How to friend with a template (alias) class defined by "template using"?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Class `B<certain X>` wants to be a friend with every `C<any,certain X>`.
I am pulling my hair out to find how to do it.

Below is the full code that successfully compiles as long as I don't add the problematic line.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum EN{ EN1,EN2 };
template<EN T1,class T2> class C{
    public: C(){
        std::cout<<T1<<std::endl;   
    }
};
template<class T2> class B{
    template<EN T1> using CT = C<T1,T2>;
    //template<EN TX> friend class CT;  //<-- error if insert this line
    public: static void test(){
        CT<EN1> ct;
    }
};

int main() {
    B<int>::test();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are what I tried (all fail):-

```
template<EN T1> friend class C<T1,T2>;  
template<EN TX> friend class CT;  
template<typename TX> friend class CT; 
template<class TX> friend class CT; 
template<class TX> friend class CT<TX>;    
template<typename> friend typename CT;
```

**Question:** What is the correct statement (1-line) to be inserted?
If possible, I want the friend statement to use `CT` rather than `C`.

I have read [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967521/class-template-with-template-class-friend-whats-really-going-on-here) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292795/template-friend), but they are simpler than mine.
(I am new to C++.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Class B wants to be a friend with every C.

Unfortunately it's impossible, because [template friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends) cannot refer to partial specializations. And this issue has nothing to do with `using`.

> Friend declarations cannot refer to partial specializations, but can refer to full specializations

You can use full specilizations as workaround, if enum `EN` doesn't have much enumerators. e.g.

```
template<class T2> class B {
    template<EN T1> using CT = C<T1, T2>;
    friend CT<EN1>; // same as friend C<EN1, T2>;
    friend CT<EN2>; // same as friend C<EN2, T2>;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Is it the same with plain C (contrast with CT)?  i.e. need 2 friend statements?

Comment: @javaLover Yes, it's same.