# Friend declaration of class template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm facing problems with friend class templates.
Here's how my code looks like

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A{
private:

  template<typename U>
  friend class A;

  int m_num = 0;

public:
//...

};
```

while

```cpp
template <typename T>
class B{
private:

  template<typename U>
  friend class B;

  template<typename U>
  friend class A; // Set A as friend class template of B

public:

  template<typename U>
  int GetNumOfA(const A<U>& a){
    return a.m_num; // Cannot Access A's private member!
  }

};
```

I expected A's private members to be accessible since I declared A as friend class of B. But it couldn't access it.
Could you help me figure out why this happens? Or any ideas to make *m_num* accessible from B?

Comment: In `A`, when you write `friend class A;`, did you mean `B`? That should make this all work...and I'm not sure what the good of making a class a friend of itself is.

Comment: Probably an X/Y problem, `friend`ship is very intrusive - perhaps a rethink of what you're trying to accomplish and thinking of a better design.

Comment: Which compiler and flags did you use? I dont seem to receive any similar errors https://godbolt.org/z/vkEHPn

Comment: @Mutable did you try to actually call the function? https://ideone.com/7iz3cA

Comment: @scohe001 you're right. How silly of me.

Answer (score 0):

You have it the wrong way around. You want `B` to be friend of `A`. So you need to declare `B` a friend in `A`'s definition:

```
template<typename T>
class A{

//...

  template<typename U>
  friend class B;

//...

};
```

Do however think about whether you *actually* want all of these classes and their different specializations to be `friend`. The point of making a member `private` is that it represents a state internal to the class and should not be accessed directly by unrelated code. Usually, if you need direct access to a member, then you should either make it `public` or if there is a class invariant that doesn't allow that, give access to it through a `public` member function which preserves the invariant.

Comment: `There is also absolutely no point to making a class friend of itself.` This code is different I [think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292852/12160191). [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/maiq5z)

Comment: @MutableSideEffect Yes right, I didn't realize that. But it is unlikely that OP actually wants all of the specializations to be friends, anyway.

Comment: @walnut  Oh, I was just silly.. thank you! As you mentioned, reason for making friend for the same class itself was to make all template specializations to be friends.